# Android app installed is double the size of the apk

Tags: android, memory, size, double, apk

I upgraded my Eclipse ADT tools to r20 (from r17 or so) and now the applications installed on the devices use twice the size of the apk. The app itself is running fine.

This happens for both the release and the debug versions, and whether I generate the apk with ant (and install thru usb) or launch the app from eclipse.

I tried with various target versions but it's always the same thing.

For info
- I do not use "copy protection" nor licensing, this is direct install, not thru the play store.
- I use proguard to optimize/obfuscate my code. I uncompresed/analyzed my apk and everything seems normal (compared to previous apk that do not exhibit this issue).

Thanks in advance for any info on that.

Comment: How did you check the size of the app? From the App Manager?

Comment: yes (on htc desire, galaxy tab, ...)

Comment: Is your device rooted?  If so, go to /data/data/<your app> and poke around.  One possibility for bloat is the libs/ folder.  On install, your architecture is detected and appropriate libraries are supposed to be copied. . .  But things can go wrong.  Maybe a database is being pre-allocated etc.

Comment: Did you try to remove the app completely from your device?

Comment: yes, and it is the same on multiple devices. This happened after I switched to adt tools v20. Before (v17) it was just fine (no "doubling" of the app size in the app manager). Also same behavior on rooted devices and non-rooted.

Answer (score 1):

Installed app's size is always  larger than apk. becoz apk is just a zipped file(copressed file) and installed app is unzipped(uncompressed).

Comment: Hi, I still have my old signed APK files. When I install them, they show 3.31 Mb in the app manager (same size as the apk file). With the newly generated APK (after moving to ADT 20) then app manager shows 6.62 Mb (but apk is 3.31).

Comment: This is not correct: APKs are not unzipped, Android access the zipped APK directly.

Comment: okk I agree with `Nikolay Elenkov` . but actual size of apk and after installation app's size is different. is it due to other data size like sqlite DB , preferences files ?

Comment: the issue is that when I was using adt tools v17, apk size and app size (in app manager) were almost the same, and now with v20 it is double the size (same project).

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue.

At the same time as the sdk update, the manifest had been updated, and the preferred storage option (external) had been deleted, So it was installed entirely on the phone memory. and the memory reported in the app manager was double the apk size.

Now it is installed on the SD card, and it uses almost the apk size in system memory as before.